# symfony call controller action in javascript with id

Tags: javascript, symfony, controller

Is it possible to call the controller action in javascript. I tried in the following way but it wont work

```
 $('#members').html({%render(controller('AmvMembersBundle:Pages:EditMembers'))%});
```

Comment: Check the documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

Answer (score 1):

Replace `{% %}` with `{{ }}`. Then it should show content.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution in this case is to put the render funciton inside a div, then control its visibility with JS.

```
<div id="members">
    <div class="edit hidden">
        {% render(controller('AmvMembersBundle:Pages:EditMembers')) %}
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#members').find('.edit').removeClass('hidden');
</script>
```

Although, if you need this to be dynamically called, you should load the controller via AJAX.